# What is the chain of actions when I close the window of an NSDocument by clicking?

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument

### The question

What happens when one click on the red button to close the window attached to an `NSDocument`?

What methods are called on which object?

Can I hook up somewhere in the process?

---

### Why I ask this question:

When I click on the red button here [image] of the window attached to the `NSDocument`, the panel

[image]

does not show up. I want to debug this, and that's why I need to know the process of actions raised by this click.

---

### More info

I put a breaking point in `- (void)windowWillClose:`. When it stops here, the window seems to be already closed and if I ask `p (bool) [self isDocumentEdited]`, I get `true`.

Comment: How is structured your document application ? Do you have multiple `NSWindowController` attached to this document ?

Comment: Yes indeed. The problem appears when I open one of these other windows (but, strangely, only for one of them). `(void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{[self.windowControllers[0] setShouldCloseDocument:YES] ;}` or `- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{[self.myWindowsManager closeAllWindows] ;}` does not help...

Comment: You need to set `-setShouldCloseDocument:` to YES for the "main" NSWindowController when you create it, or once you open other window. Changing it while `-windowWillClose:`, it's to late.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I guess putting it in `windowWillClose:` was too late. Or maybe `self.windowControllers[0]` was the wrong controller. I hook on the right controller via `- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController` where for once, I use the argument. It does not answer my question but solve my problem perfectly!

Comment: `-windowWillClose:` is send from the `-close`method. So after that all checks are done in `-performClose:`
The save panel is invoke in `-performClose:` before sending [-windowShouldClose:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowShouldClose:) to the `NSWindow` delegate see `NSDocument` methods `-shouldCloseWindowController:delegate:shouldCloseSelector:contextInfo:`, and `-canCloseDocumentWithDelegate:shouldCloseSelector:contextInfo:`